# How to access module attributes such as the stride of convolutions from jit::script::module

Tags: pytorch, jit, libtorch, torchscript

I am currently writing a C++ program which needs to do some analyses of the structure of a CNN model in torchScript format. I am using the C++ torch library the way it is shown on torch.org, loading in the model like so:

```
#include <torch/script.h>
#include <torch/torch.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "usage: example-app <path-to-exported-script-module>\n";
        return -1;
    }

    torch::jit::script::Module module;
    try {
        // Deserialize the ScriptModule from a file using torch::jit::load().
        module = torch::jit::load(argv[1]);
    }
    catch (const c10::Error& e) {
        std::cerr << "error loading the model\n";
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As far as I was able to figure out `module` consists of a collection of nested `torch::jit::script::Module`'s the lowest of which represent the built in functions. Im accessing those lowest modules as follows:

```
void print_modules(const torch::jit::script::Module& imodule) {

    for (const auto& module : imodule.named_children()) {

        if(module.value.children().size() > 0){
            print_modules(module.value);

        }
        else{

            std::cout << module.name << "\n";

        }
    }
}
```

This function recursively goes trough the modules and prints the name of the lowest level ones, which correspond to the builtin functions of torch script.

**My question now is, how do I access the details for those builtin functions like for example the stride length for convolutions?**

I can't figure out for the life of me to get access to those basic attributes of modules.

Comment: I would print the module name also for the intermediate level. Also, adding an integer value input `indentation` (default value 0) you could have the modules indented as you go deeper in your module. Something like [this](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/407e4f2286c025af) (I tested it locally, it seems to work).

Comment: Does C++ torchscript support calling functions?
You could write a python function that outputs the details you want and annotate it with `@torch.jit.export`
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71392971/torchscript-call-other-function-rather-than-forward