# Torchscript call other function rather than forward

Tags: pytorch, torch, torchscript

When I compile my torch model to torchscript I can make use of the function `forward` by just calling the torchscript model object `model()`.

But when I want to use another function created on the model I cant call the function. I try to do `model.functionName()` expecting to call the function `functionName` but nothing happens.

Any idea on how could I call subfunctions from the model object that are not forward?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to apply the change only on that model or also on its layers?

Comment: Also, is this a temporal change or you want to just replace the original `forward`?

Comment: I dont get what you mean but change on model or layers. Is not a temporal change and it wont replace the forward neither. Is a function similar to the forward one, but where I convert float tensors to strings with a torchtext layer vocab() that the model has. Since the output type is different torchscript doesnt allow me to have both logics within one function, I need to create a different one.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should add [decorator](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html#torch.jit.export) `@torch.jit.export` above the method you want to call and convert torchscript model again. After that you can call method by `module.run_method(name, args)` [docs](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e813eaee22be2bfe5e6f2a137305cffe864a01da/torch/csrc/jit/api/object.h#L165).